# I am attempting to integrate a sine wave. I am getting a valueError: invalid callable given

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate


time = np.arange(0.0, 1, 0.0001)
test = np.sin(time)

test2 = integrate.quad(test,0,0.01)
```

I set up time with np.arange
I then create the sin function
I then attempt to integrate the function

```
Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/memresistor/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    test = integrate.quad(test,0,0.01)
  File "/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/memresistor/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_quadpack_py.py", line 351, in quad
    retval = _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit,
  File "/home/andrew/PycharmProjects/memresistor/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/integrate/_quadpack_py.py", line 463, in _quad
    return _quadpack._qagse(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit)
ValueError: invalid callable given
```

Comment: To integrate sin from 0 to 1, you should be calling `integrate.quad(np.sin, 0, 1)`.  The first argument to `integrate.quad` is the function itself, not its vlaues.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the misunderstanding: `np.sin` is a function. `np.sin()` is not. When the `()` is added to the end, the function is called and will be evaluated, thus no longer being a function. Does this work for you?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate

test = integrate.quad(np.sin, 0, 1)
```

Comment: It does work. However I need to use np.arange to create a plot for matplotlib. Is there anyway you know of I can do that after integration? I also need the sin function to have scalars such as *5 etc

Comment: If you describe the plot you want to make I might be able to help, but doing this integration just computes a value, you can do whatever you want before or afterwards.

Comment: -I need to plot an integrated sin wave that has been scaled. for example sin*5

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "integrated sin wave" because the integral of sine is just negative cosine, and you can plot a scaled cosine easily.

Comment: Sorry, It's been 7 years since I've taken trig I forgot. Thank you!

Comment: No worries, happy to help.